# CFG for this language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Give a CFG for the language $\{x \in \{a,b\}^* | x \not= ww \text{ for some w} \in \{a,b\}^*$

In my attempt to do this I understand odd length strings are automatically in the language, but don't know how to handle even length strings. What would the CFG look like? I know it starts with S-> E|U when E is the even case and U the uneven case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A detailed answer can be found here: [not-square-words-are-context-free-and-not-regular](https://carlocomin.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/not-square-words-are-context-free-and-not-regular/). According to this answer, the grammar
\begin{align}
S &\to AB + BA + A + B  \\
A &\to aAa + aAb + bAa + bAb + a \\
B &\to aBa + aBb + bBa + bBb + b
\end{align}
generates the set of non-square words of $\{a,b \}^*$.