# Find a Context-Free Grammar for this Context-Free Language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

$$
L = \{w_1w_2 : w_1, w_2\, \in \, \{a,b\}^*, w_1 \ne w_2\}
$$
So far I have produced this grammar which will produce a string of odd length which follows that $w_1$ and $w_2$ wouldn't be equal.
$$
S \to aSa\,|\,aSb\,|\,bSa\,|\,bSb\,|\,a\,|\,b
$$

Comment: I do not address cases of empty string which I believe should be included? Should I provide another vector from which to get terminals from?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529917/cfg-for-this-language

Comment: The language your definition specifies is probably not the one you intended. Hagen von Eitzen's answer is correct, for your question in its present form. What you *intend* is (likely) the language defined in the [question Math1000 suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529917/cfg-for-this-language). Why aren't these the same? Because you just say "Take any two unequal strings of $\{a, b\}^*$ and concatenate them". Here's one: $w_1 = aba$, $w_2 = b$. Clearly, $w_1 \ne w_2$. But $w_1w_2 = abab$. This *can* be written in the form $ww$ (for $w = ab$). But it's a valid string of $L$.

Comment: @M.Vinay Indeed that is how I interpreted the question since the alternative is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $L=\{a,b\}^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$. Hence $$S\to aS|bS|a|b $$
should do it.